# How can I create an ad-hoc connection from my Macbook Pro wifi connection?

Tags: macos, wifi, airport, ad-hoc

My Macbook Pro using a Wifi internet connection & I would like to share this connection to other systems in my house. When I tried to configure by myself I don't see the usual "airport" option to create the ad-hoc connection.

How can I do this in lion OS X?

Comment: I took out the question about your router; it is a separate question from the one about the ad-hoc network.

Comment: OK, it's fine for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can only share Internet from an Ethernet, Bluetooh, or FireWire connection over Wi-Fi.

That's because you can only use your Wi-Fi connection for one thing at a time. If you're connecting to the Internet over Wi-Fi you won't be able to share that connection over Wi-Fi.

If you've got Share your connection from: set to Wi-Fi, it's normal that To computers using: doesn't have a Wi-Fi option:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Based upon my understanding of your description of the problem, this is not a question of configuring your MacBook Pro. If you have a Linksys E2000 WiFi router, you do not need to share the Internet connection "ad-hoc" *from* the MacBook Pro. In fact, this would be counterproductive.

This is a matter of learning to use your Linksys E2000 router to connect multiple computers to your Internet connection. Here is [a link to the support page for the Linksys E2000](http://homesupport.cisco.com/en-us/support/routers/E2000). You can read the user manual and the FAQ.